# batch file to read write comma delimted text file

Tags: csv, batch-file

I need help reading/writing a comma delimeted text file WHILE excluding the rows which do not have sufficient data in them. Following is a sample text file. The last 2 rows should be excluded from the NewFile.csv

```
DepositDate,Batch,Trans,CkSeq,AcctNum,CkAmnt,R/T,CkNum,,Amnt,crxtal,cdv,OCRScanLine,DRNum
05/19/2014,3621,1,1,22800,50.00,1123444,047886,100,50.00,8,9,000473865000000050009,165289
05/19/2014,3622,1,1,7704094,50.00,684335879,006450,,,,,,
05/19/2014,11075,1,,,,,,,,,,,
05/19/2014,11075,2,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Here is my code:

```
::clear variables
Set _var1=
Set _var2=
Set _var3=
Set _var4=
Set _var5=
Set _var6=
Set _var7=
Set _var8=
Set _var9=
Set _var10=
Set _var11=
Set _var12=
Set _var13=
Set _var13=
Set _var14=
Set _var99=

::start loop through file skipping header row, identifying 14 fields and a comma delimeter
FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1-14* delims=," %%A IN (with.csv) DO (

::set variables for the row values
Set _var1=%%A
Set _var2=%%B
Set _var3=%%C
Set _var4=%%D
Set _var5=%%E
Set _var6=%%F
Set _var7=%%G
Set _var8=%%H
Set _var9=%%I
Set _var10=%%J
Set _var11=%%K
Set _var12=%%L
Set _var13=%%M
Set _var14=%%N
::echo a variable to verify it is populated with data...DOESN'T WORK!
echo._var1 %_var1%

::concatenate the 12 rightmost tokens into a string to verify if they are all blank
Set _var99=%_var3%%_var4%%_var5%%_var6%%_var7%%_var8%%_var9%%_var10%%_var11%%_var12%%_var13%%_var14%
pause

CALL :PROCESS
)

GOTO :EOF

:PROCESS
echo._var99 %_var99%
pause

::test if _var99 is all blank then don't write that row to the new file.
if NOT %_var99%=="" echo %_var1%,%_var2%,%_var3%,%_var4%,%_var5%,%_var6%,%_var7%,%_var8%,%_var9%,%_var10%,%_var11%,%_var12%,%_var13%,%_var14% >>NewFile.csv
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: so what problem are you seeing?  fyi, before the last line, you need you to put `""` around the var, like so `if NOT "!_var99!"==""`.  You also need to use delayed expansion and subsitute the `%` for `!` for everything needed to be expanded inside your loop. For example, `echo !_var1!,!_var2!` etc.

Comment: What's wrong with `findstr /ve ",,,,,,,,,,," with.csv > NewFile.csv` instead using a `for` loop?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use delayed expansion if you are going to expand a variable within a loop that was set within the same loop. That requires `setlocal enableDelayedExpansion`, and `!var!` instead of `%var%`.

But you still can have problems because you don't verify that the first 3 columns are populated. That is not an easy task using FOR /F.

There is a simple one line solution using FINDSTR and MORE. MORE is used to skip the first line, and FINDSTR only preserves lines that have the first 3 columns populated, plus at least one more populated column after that.

```
findstr "^[^,][^,]*,[^,][^,]*,[^,][^,]*,*[^,]" with.csv|more +1 >newFile.csv
```

The above will fail (hang) if the output has more than 64K lines due to a limitation of MORE. If this is a problem, then you can use an additional FINDSTR instead, assuming none of your data lines contain the header text.

```
findstr "^[^,][^,]*,[^,][^,]*,[^,][^,]*,*[^,]" with.csv|findstr /vb DepositDate >newFile.csv
```

Note that this method cannot be extended indefinitely because FINDSTR is limited to at most 15 character class expressions in a search string.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    (   for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%a in (with.csv
        ) do for /f "tokens=4 delims=," %%b in ("%%a"
        ) do echo(%%a
    ) > newFile.csv

    endlocal
```

It is a "relaxed" check of the contents of the file. What it does is iterate over the input file (skipping the first line) and for each line in it, tokenize the line and try to obtain the 4th comma delimited token. If the line does not contain at least 4 columns with data, there is no possibility to populate the fourth token and the code in the inner `for` loop (output the original line) will not be executed.

But as indicated, this is a "relaxed" check. It does not test which four columns contains data.